# Finding contour integral of $e^{t(z+z^{-1})}z^{-2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am really struggling with a contour integration question, which I am revising for an exam. I want to show that the contour integral of

$$\int_\Gamma e^{t(z+z^{-1})}z^{-2} dz=\sum_{m=0}^\infty b_mt^{2m+1}$$ where the $b_m$ are constants to be found, and $\Gamma$ is the positively oriented circle with centre $0$ and radius $R$.

I was wondering, as I instinctivey noticed that $z+z^{-1}=2cos(\theta)$ where, $z=Re^{i\theta}$ if we should rewrite this integral, so that it becomes $$\int _0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2tRcos(\theta)}}{(Re^{i\theta})^2(iRe^{i\theta})}d\theta$$

But then, I don't see that this has any poles at all? Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why is $z+z^{-1}=2\cos\theta$ when $z=Re^{i\theta}$, $R\neq 1$?  You have an essential singularity at $z=0$ because of the $z^{-1}$ inside $\exp$.

Comment: I see, I was originally thinking there was an essential singularity-but then if I have an essential singularity, how can I apply the Residue Theorem?

Comment: Note the $t$ appears with $z+z^{-1}$, so coefficient of $t^m$ comes from integrating the appropriate Laurent polynomial and there is no convergence issue to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{tz} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}t^n\frac{z^n}{n!}\,,$$
$$e^{t/z} = \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}t^m\frac{z^{-m}}{m!}\,.$$

Therefore, the integrand is:

$$e^{tz}e^{t/z}z^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}
t^{n+m}\frac{z^{n-m-2}}{n!m!}\,.$$

For each value of $m$, we pick a residue from the singularity at the origin only when $n=m+1$, (with residue $t^{2m+1}/m!(m+1)!$). Therefore the value of the integral is:

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\pi i}{m!(m+1)!}t^{2m+1}\,.$$

The value of $b_m$ is:

$$b_m = \frac{2\pi i}{m!(m+1)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$e^{t\left(z+z^{-1}\right)}z^{-2}=z^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^{n}}{n!}\left(z+z^{-1}\right)^{n}=\\\\=z^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^{n}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}z^{-k}z^{n-k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^{n}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}z^{n-2\left(k+1\right)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\oint_{\Gamma}{\expo{t\pars{z + z^{-1}}} \over z^{2}}\,\dd z & =
\oint_{\Gamma}{\expo{tz}\expo{t/z} \over z^{2}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\Gamma}{\bracks{\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\pars{tz}^{m}/m!} \bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{t/z}^{n}/n!} \over z^{2}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{t^{m + n} \over m!\, n!}\
\overbrace{\oint_{\Gamma}{\dd z \over z^{2 - m + n}}}
^{\ds{2\pi\ic\,\delta_{2 - m + n,1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}
{2\pi\ic \over m!\pars{m - 1}!}\,t^{m + \pars{m - 1}}\bracks{m - 1 \geq 0}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\
\underbrace{2\pi\ic \over \pars{m + 1}!\,m!}_{\ds{ b_{m}}}\ t^{2m + 1}}
\end{align}

Comment: Surely there must be factorials in the expansion of $e^z$.

Comment: @Maxim Fixed. I became almost blind for awhile. Thanks.